# ASP.NET + Umbraco + SQL Server - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, umbraco

I'm trying to setup a local version of a website that's online and working. The site is built with Umbraco V6, and is using an SQL Server database. My test server is a fresh install of Server Standard 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

My process has been to:

1. Install the O/S and SQL Server
2. Setup a test Umbraco site in IIS, installing from scratch into a fresh database
3. Once 2. is working, download the source code from the live server and install in a new site in IIS
4. Download a copy of the live SQL Server database and restore it into the server
5. Add a new user account into SQL Server, granting permissions onto the SQL database i've restored

When I try to access the website through a browser, I get an error. This shows up in IIS as:

> **Event Code 3005. An unhandled exception has occurred. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

I've disabled the Windows Firewall and have checked I can telnet into the server on port 1433. I know the Web.config is using the right credentials, as I can change it to a different user account and see a different error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the steps listed over here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/07/19/tcp-provider-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it.aspx

I suspect that your connection string is pointing to the wrong server instance or that the TCP protocol is not configured correctly.

Tip: You can always copy and paste the settings from your connectionstring into the Connect Object Explorer of SQL Management Studio to verify that they work.